# Syncfusion - background color for page number

Tags: c#, pdf, background, syncfusion

I use Syncfusion (Version=16.4200.0.46) to convert html to pdf. In footer, I use PdfPageNumberField class to draw page number.

How can I set background color for this element?

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion does not have a default option to achieve your requirement, but it is possible to achieve using the below workaround.

```
void CreatePDF()
{
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Pages.Add();
    document.Pages.Add();

    AddFooter(document);
    document.Save("Sample.pdf");
    document.Close(true);
}


void AddFooter(PdfDocument doc)
{
    RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, doc.Pages[0].GetClientSize().Width, 50);
    PdfPageTemplateElement footer = new PdfPageTemplateElement(rect);
    PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 8);
    PdfSolidBrush brush = new PdfSolidBrush(Color.Gray);

    PdfPageNumberField pageNumber = new PdfPageNumberField(font, brush);

    PdfPageCountField count = new PdfPageCountField(font, brush);

    string pageNumberFormat = "Page {0} of {1}";
    PointF pageNumberLocation = new PointF(100, 20);
    SizeF dimensionOfPageNumber = font.MeasureString(pageNumberFormat);

    footer.Graphics.DrawRectangle(PdfBrushes.Aquamarine, 
        new RectangleF(new PointF(pageNumberLocation.X - 5F, pageNumberLocation.Y), dimensionOfPageNumber));

    PdfCompositeField compositeField = new PdfCompositeField(font, PdfBrushes.Black, pageNumberFormat, pageNumber, count);
    compositeField.Draw(footer.Graphics, pageNumberLocation);

    doc.Template.Bottom = footer;
}
```

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.